# Best way to map multiple values to one property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following objects, which represent a survey that consists of a collection of questions and their possible answer options:

```
{ "surveyTitle": "Survey 1", "questionText": "Question 1?", "questionId": 1, "offeredAnswerText": "Answer 1", "offeredAnswerId": 1 },
{ "surveyTitle": "Survey 1", "questionText": "Question 1?", "questionId": 1, "offeredAnswerText": "Answer 2", "offeredAnswerId": 2 },
{ "surveyTitle": "Survey 1", "questionText": "Question 2?", "questionId": 2, "offeredAnswerText": "Answer 3", "offeredAnswerId": 3 }
```

This is coming from an INNER JOIN on my table and it's not in a great state to pass to the front-end. I'm trying to modify the survey object so I can group by questions first, and then map the answer options to their question so they look like this:

`question: { id: int, text: string, answerOptions: [] }`

where an `answerOption` is consisted of a `text` and `id`:

`answerOption: { offeredAnswerId, offeredAnswerText }`

I have the following expression:

```
const questions = _.chain(rows).groupBy("id").map((question, i) => ({
        id: i,
        text: question[0].questionText,
        answerOptions: _.map(question, 'offeredAnswerText')
    })).value();
```

Which works great so far, but I want the `answerOptions` array to also include the full `answerOption` object, which is the id and text as shown above.

I am using lodash in my project to help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the wanted properties directly. And take `questionId` instead of `id` for grouping.

```js
var rows = [{ "surveyTitle": "Survey 1", "questionText": "Question 1?", "questionId": 1, "offeredAnswerText": "Answer 1", "offeredAnswerId": 1 }, { "surveyTitle": "Survey 1", "questionText": "Question 1?", "questionId": 1, "offeredAnswerText": "Answer 2", "offeredAnswerId": 2 }, { "surveyTitle": "Survey 1", "questionText": "Question 2?", "questionId": 2, "offeredAnswerText": "Answer 3", "offeredAnswerId": 3 }],
    questions = _.chain(rows)
        .groupBy("questionId")
        .map((question, id) => ({
            id,
            text: question[0].questionText,
            answerOptions: _.map(question, ({ offeredAnswerId, offeredAnswerText }) => ({ offeredAnswerId, offeredAnswerText }))
        }))
        .value();

console.log(questions);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```